# For Get and Post request a new session is being generated which throws TokenMismatchException in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, csrf-protection

I am working with simple login application, where there is a form of login on "`GET`" Request. On get request a session file is created in "`storage/framework/session/`" folder. That includes the `csrf-token` on the form equivalent to session token but, when I a submit that form with post request again a session file had been created which holds different `csrf-token` value. So, it seems when both token has been compared they didn't match ie. "`form-csrf-token`" and "`session-csrf-token`". Ultimately it throws `TokenMismatchException`.

I want to know that how can I fix this?

I don't want to use `CSRF verification` exclusion, because it will become a big security issue for me to not to use `CSRF Verification`.

I am using `Form façade blade template` to generate a `Form`.

Here is the code of **route.php**

```
    Route::get('/', function(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect('home');
    }
    return view('pages.index');
    });

    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('home', 'PageController@home')->middleware(['auth']);
    Route::get('about','PageController@about');
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
```

**Auth\AuthController.php**

```
    class AuthController extends Controller
    {
        use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'FirstName'   => 'required|max:255',
            'Gender'        => 'required|in:Male,Female,Trans',
            'DateOfBirth'   => 'required|date|before:today',
            'email'         => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
            'password'      => 'required|min:6',
            'confirmed'     => 'required|same:password'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'FirstName' => $data['FirstName'],
            'Surname' => $data['surname'],
            'DateOfBirth' => $data['DateOfBirth'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'Gender' => $data['Gender']
        ]);
    }
}
```

**loginsignup.blade.php**

```
<div class="w3-container">
<div class="w3-row w3-padding-top w3-right">
    <div class="col left">
        <h3>Create an account</h3>
        <h5>It's free and always will be.</h5>
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'auth/register','method'=>'POST','id'=>'formRegister')) !!}
    <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="text" class="w3-input register" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="text" class="w3-input register" id="surname" name="surname" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">Surname</label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="date" class="w3-input register" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">Date of Birth</label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="text" class="w3-input register" id="email" name="email" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="password" class="w3-input register" id="password" name="password" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">New password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="password" class="w3-input register" id="confirmed" name="confirmed" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">Re-enter password</label>
            </div>
            <label class="w3-checkbox w3-text-theme">
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" checked>
                <span class="w3-checkmark"></span> Male
            </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label class="w3-checkbox w3-text-theme">
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female">
                <span class="w3-checkmark"></span> Female
            </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label class="w3-checkbox w3-text-theme">
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Trans">
                <span class="w3-checkmark"></span> Trans
            </label>
        <br><br>
            <button class="w3-btn w3-theme"> Create an account </button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col right">
        <button class="btn facebook" data-provider="facebook"><i></i><span>Facebook</span></button>
        <button class="btn twitter" data-provider="twitter"><i></i><span>Twitter</span></button>
        <button class="btn plus" data-provider="google plus"><span class="i"><i></i></span><span>Google Plus</span></button>
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'auth/login','method'=>'POST','id'=>'formLogin')) !!}
            <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="email" class="w3-input" id="email" name="email" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">Email or phone</label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-group">
                <input type="password" class="w3-input" id="password" name="password" required>
                <label class="w3-label w3-text-theme">Password</label>
            </div>
            <label class="w3-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember">
                <div class="w3-checkmark"></div> Stay Logged In
            </label>
            <div class="w3-group"><a href="password/email"> Forgot Your Password ?</a></div>
            <button id="signInSubmit" type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-theme">Submit</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Steps I followed and analysed problem

[This is when I first opened http://localhost:8000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjOxE.png)

[After sending form using post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V43pb.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Show us the code ? Without code, we are at least possible help for you.

Comment: Here is the link of my code, it's on github https://github.com/mramitkumarraj/bloger

Comment: I do not want the repository and/or your complete application.. Just the code where you think the error is.

Comment: I am really apologize to say but, that's the thing i couldn't find, because it's a laravel framework code which compare both tokens. It's in "verifycsrftoken.php" file line no 52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer by self. Actually it's not a problem. It happens when a session has been generated for the system after being logged in.

You need to get logged out from application.

That's it.